# Printing invalid C string succeeds

Tags: c, string, null, printf

I accidentally missed a colon when writing the initializer list of some strings array, and that made me observe that `printf` can succeed in printing an invalid (`0x0`) string. Here is my C file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
const char *names[3]=
{
    "a",
    "b" // missing colon here made names[1] == "bc"
    "c"
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("name [2] = %s",names[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compiled and executed it I got `name [2] = (null)` which is "weird" because I think it makes much more sense to just crash the application, no? The reason I had a hard time finding it is because some of the strings I use are not `"b"` and `"c"` but rather words like `null`, `nothing` etc.
**My questions are**: (1) why no warning is issued? (2) how come `printf` has this default behavior?

Comment: The [C11 Standard 7.21.6.1 says](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1) "the argument [associated with `"%s"`] shall be a pointer to the initial element of an array of character type". Yours isn't so you invoke UB: anything can happen, including expected and/or unexpected results.

Comment: Printing a null pointer is UB, as denoted by @pmg, some implementations allow printing the null pointer as an extension, though (e. g. MSVC does, if I remember correctly).

Comment: *"(2) how come printf has this default behavior?"* -- it doesn't. It is how the specific implementation you are using has chosen to save you from yourself when you pass a null pointer to `printf`. (which is how glibc does it if I recall). I'm sure it checks the pointer, e.g. `if (!ptr)` and if that tests true, then outputs `"(null)"`.

Comment: You have my sympathies -- this can be a real nuisance.  I've been burned by this sort of thing, too.  It would indeed be nice if the compiler could somehow warn about the missing comma -- but at the same time, its hard to see how the compiler could warn about the missing comma, because it's perfectly legal code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is that of string concatenation in your initializer! In the code:

```
const char *names[3]=
{
    "a",
    "b" // missing colon here made names[1] == "bc"
    "c"
};
```

The literals `"b"` and `"c"` will be concatenated into a single value, `"bc"` and, thus, the third element of the `names[]` array will be initialized to zero (a null pointer).

***There is no warning because such initialisation of strings is perfectly legitimate `C` code.***

Your code is, effectively:

```
const char *names[3]=
{
    "a",
    "bc"
};
```

which is, in turn, the same as:

```
const char *names[3]=
{
    "a",
    "bc",
    NULL
};
```

Further, as mentioned in the comments (**pmg** and **David C. Rankin**), the behaviour of `printf("%s", x)"` when `x` is a null pointer is *undefined behaviour*. As **Aconcagua** has pointed out, many (or most) compilers will do as yours has, and print `{null}` or some such; but some systems may crash.